# servlet compiling error

Tags: servlets

Can anyone please help me with compiling servlet? Do I have to include path for JDK or Tomcat or both to compile servlet in command prompt?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825652/compiling-a-servlet-in-windows-xp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need servlet.jar in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need to include at least the Servlet API in the classpath. Tomcat has it in flavor of `servlet-api.jar` in its `/lib` folder.

So you basically need to compile your servlets like:

```
javac -cp .;c:/path/to/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar com/example/SomeServlet.java
```